# How can I call a function in another CFC file from within a query of a function in one cfc file?

Tags: sql, methods, coldfusion, invoke

I have one cfc file (info.cfc) with multiple functions as shown below.

```
<cfcomponent output="true" extends="DateFunctions">
    <cffunction name="getStatuses" access="remote" returntype="any" output="true" returnformat="plain">
       ...
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="viewDate" access="remote" returntype="any" output="true" returnformat="plain">
        <cfquery  name="records">
              SELECT
                 dbo.tickets.Incident,
                 dbo.tickets.Start_Date,
                 dbo.tickets.Days_Due
              FROM
                 dbo.tickets    
        </cfquery>
    </cffunction>
</component>
```

And the other cfc file (DateFunctions.cfc) containing the a function with two arguments and returning a date.
The DateFunctions.cfc file is as follows:

```
<cfcomponent output="true" name="DateFunctions"">
    <cffunction name="addBusinessDays" access="remote" returntype="any" output="true" returnformat="plain">
       <cfargument name="daysToAdd" 
                required="yes" 
                type="numeric" 
                hint="The number of whole business days to add or subtract from the given date">
        <cfargument name="date" 
                required="No" 
                type="date" 
                hint="The date object to start counting from.." 
                default="#NowDateTime#">

         ...
         ... <!--- Perform some tasks --->

         <cfreturn Date>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Question: How can I invoke "addBusinessDays" from within the query in (info.cfc) also producing another column of results.

I thought I might have been able to do something like:

```
<cffunction name="viewDate" access="remote" returntype="any" output="true" returnformat="plain">
    <cfquery  name="records">
          SELECT
             dbo.tickets.Incident,
             dbo.tickets.Start_Date,
             dbo.tickets.Days_Due,
             (
               <cfinvoke component="DateFunctions" method="addBusinessDays" returnVariable="Date">
                  <cfinvokeargument name="daysToAdd" value="#dbo.tickets.Days_Due#">
                  <cfinvokeargument name="date" value="#dbo.tickets.Start_Date#">
               </cfinvoke>
             ) AS Due_DATE
          FROM
             dbo.tickets    
    </cfquery>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: This processing should  be done on view page when HTML is generated

Comment: In order to answer this, we need to see the code for addBusinessDays.

Comment: (Edit) CFC's cannot be used that way.  The ColdFusion server and the database are totally separate.  CF knows nothing about database objects, and the database knows nothing about CFML, so you cannot mix the two that way. ColdFusion's only job is to act as a messenger. It does its work *before* the query ever executes. CF evaluates any cfml code and converts everything into literals. It then builds a SQL string and sends that string to the database for execution. The database does the rest.

Comment: (Edit) Also, depending on the actual logic of addBusinessDays, you might consider moving the logic to the database and using either a) calendar database table with a JOIN instead OR b) scalar database function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following with the caveat of there would be additional processing for the loop.

Edit: Per discussion below, updated cfoutput to cfloop

```
 <cffunction name="viewDate" access="remote" returntype="any" output="true" returnformat="plain">
    <cfquery  name="records">
          SELECT
             dbo.tickets.Incident,
             dbo.tickets.Start_Date,
             dbo.tickets.Days_Due, 
            '' as Due_DATE
          FROM
             dbo.tickets    
    </cfquery>

    <cfset df = createobject("component","DateFunctions")>

    <cfloop query="records">
        <cfset records.Due_DATE = df.addBusinessDays(Days_Due, Start_Date)>
    </cfloop>

   <cfreturn records>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: 1) Do not forget to VAR/LOCAL scope all function local variables (query names too) 2) Drop the "dbo.tablename" from the CF loop. It is not part of the query column name 3) Since the code is not displaying anything, use `cfloop` rather than `cfoutput`

Comment: Also 4) Do not use  ` '' as Due_DATE` ' because it will not generate the correct data type and/or size for the new column. Instead use something like `CAST(NULL AS datetime) AS Due_Date`. The exact syntax is dbms specific.

Comment: cfloop vs cfoutput is a matter of preference, unless nested loops are involved.  I'm not sure that the casting in this case really matters either for anything other than readability.  Good point on the dbo.tablename, which I can correct.  And I agree on the scoping (but never actually do it).

Comment: Casting does matter. Using an empty string creates a varchar column. When the values are used in date functions or comparisons (which they almost certainly will be) it will require an implicit conversion, which is unnecessary and error prone. Using the correct data type up front avoids that. *RE: cfloop vs cfoutput*  The code is not outputting anything. Why would you want to use a tag designed specifically for output just to loop through a query? It is the wrong tool for the job ;-)

Comment: I don't see anywhere in CF documentation where cfoutput is only intended for display.  I've always interpreted cfoutput meaning of the output of data, whether it's a variable or query result.  A quick scan online shows there is little performance difference.  Also, I've used cfoutput's grouping attribute to simplify the forming of json data - something cfloop  can't in of itself do.  

And Coldfusion is pretty much typeless - doesn't it really preserve the datatype of a query column?  :)

Comment: IMHO: functions should be set to `output="false"` unless it is really expected that the function generate output. In my code it is more common to see a function return a string than generate output. This is related to: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187457/what-is-the-principle-of-least-astonishment

Comment: @snackboy - It is [right there in the docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfoutput.html):  "*Displays* output ...".  You are talking about variable assignment. Not the same thing. *RE: doesn't it really preserve the datatype of a query column* Huh? :) That is the point. Query columns are not typeless. The sql creates a column with the wrong data type. CFLoop actually supports grouping now. Though for older versions, yes that is one of the few legitimate use cases for misusing cfoutput.

Comment: @JamesAMohler - Agreed, on suppressing output when not needed. I was just remarking on the unnecessary use of cfoutput in this context. The docs have gotten better, but .. there are still a lot of poor examples floating around, full of excess pound signs, quotes, and abuses of cfoutput ;-). It is not just that the examples are ugly code, they help foster a lot of misconceptions and misunderstandings about certain aspects of cfml IMO.

Comment: @Leigh - It's always a good day when I [re]learn something new.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep :) You might also be interested in [this new discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779101/are-there-different-kinds-of-nulls) James opened about casting nulls.

Comment: @Leigh - Your solution worked for me... Thank you!!

However, when outputting the data to the webpage in a jqGrid, but i am unable to sort (asc or desc) indexing on that "Due_Date" column of that grid. Does that have anything to do with using CAST NULL. 

How can I rectify that?

Comment: @AkimGeorge - The solution above was posted by snackboy. jqGrid is javascript. Like most jQuery plugins, it probably requires the JSON results to be formatted in a specific way, but that is a totally different ball of wax. Search the archives first.  I see a few results on [dates not sorting as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868036/jqgrid-not-sorting-dates-correctly).  If you do not find an answer, open a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating the df object, it should be tied to the `this` scope. That way the object is created only once. This should make the `viewDate` function run faster as there is no overhead in creating `df`.

Also, `new` is just a cleaner syntax

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cfset this.df =  new DateFunctions()>

    <cffunction name="viewDate" access="remote" returntype="any" output="false" returnformat="plain">
        <cfquery  name="Local.records">
           SELECT
                dbo.tickets.Incident,
                dbo.tickets.Start_Date,
                dbo.tickets.Days_Due, 
                CAST(NULL AS datetime)
           FROM
                dbo.tickets    
       </cfquery>


      <cfloop query="Local.records">
         <cfset Local.records.Due_DATE = this.df.addBusinessDays( Local.records.Days_Due, Local.records.Start_Date)>
      </cfloop>

      <cfreturn Local.records>
    </cffunction>

<cfcomponent>
```

Comment: I realize the above is based on the previous answer, but as [mentioned in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757359/how-can-i-call-a-function-in-another-cfc-file-from-within-a-query-of-a-function#comment63005512_37759519), `'' as Due_DATE` should be replaced with something like `CAST(NULL AS datetime)` (dbms specific) to ensure the correct column type.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779101/are-there-different-kinds-of-nulls