# sorting dates in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, jqgrid

The date column is not being sorted properly on client, see my code, last column is the date one and the date comes in dd-MMM-YYYY format - e.g. 13-Jul-2020

Anything off here?

```
 $('#myGrid').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        url: pathvar
        jsonReader: common.jqgrid.jsonReader(),
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: [
            'Quote Id', 'Client', 'Title', 'Assignee', 'Due Date'],

        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'QuoteId',
                index: 'QuoteId',
                width: 10,
                sortable: false,
                search: false                    
            },
            {
                name: 'ClientCode',
                index: 'ClientCode',
                width: 10,
                sortable: false,
                search: false,
                formatter: WebView.followups.onClientLinkFormatter
            },
            {
                name: 'Title',
                index: 'Title',
                width: 30,
                sortable: false,
                search: false,
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                name: 'AssignedUser',
                index: 'AssignedUser',
                width: 20,
                sortable: false,
                search: true
            },
            {
                name: 'DueDate',
                index: 'DueDate',
                width: 15,
                sortable: true,
                search: false,
                sorttype: 'date',
                srcformat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',                   
                formatoptions: { newformat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY' }
            }

        ],

        scroll: false,
        hidegrid: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 1000,
        rowNum: 1000,
        altRows: true,
        loadonce: true,
        sortable: true,
        altclass: 'gridAltRowClass',
        loadComplete: function (data) {},
        gridComplete: function () {

 var rows = $("#quoteFollowupsGrid").getDataIDs();
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var duedate = $("#quoteFollowupsGrid").getCell(rows[i], "DueDate");

                    const today = moment();
                    var rowDueDate = moment(duedate, 'DD-MMM-YYYY'); // new Date(duedate + "00:00:00");

                    if (rowDueDate == today)
                        $("#quoteFollowupsGrid").jqGrid('setRowData', rows[i], false, { background: '#c6e3c4' });
                    else if (rowDueDate < today)
                        $("#quoteFollowupsGrid").jqGrid('setRowData', rows[i], false, { background: '#ffc4d2' });
                }

        }

    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868416/556586

Comment: @murat aras I saw that answer already but it did not help me. It makes no sense at all if you read it. Very confusing which formats to add and where

Comment: The important part here is which version of jqGrid is used? - commercial Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= version 4.7? Moreover you have code in gridComplete or loadComplete which can destroy the sorting- so it is a good idea to see this code.

Comment: @Tony Tomov I updated the code in gridComplete

Comment: The sorting does not work even if there is no code in loadComplete and gridComplete though so I don't think that this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

In Guriddo jqGrid JS this is a bug. If you use this version, please write a email to the support to receive the fixed version.

Comment: Hi Tony, I don't know who Gurido is but I use jquery 2.1.0. Do you suggest doing this on the server instead? It's a bit of an overkill in this particular case so I was hoping to do it on the client.

Comment: We found that the loadComplete and gridComplete  and jQuery version are not related to the problem. The problem is in the code and you should know which version of jqGrid is used -  open the jqGrid file and at the beginning you will see a version info.

Comment: I am using Jqgrid version 2.1.0 - sorry I meant jqgrid not jquery. Anyways i don't have time  to research and upgrade so I just moved it to the server